# Is a contracted primary ideal the contraction of a primary ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

This questions is motivated by [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2305460/660).

Let $A\to B$ be a morphism of commutative rings and $\mathfrak q$ a contracted primary ideal in $A$ (that is, an ideal of $A$ which is contracted and primary).

> **Question 1** Is there a primary ideal $\mathfrak r$ in $B$ whose contraction $\mathfrak r^c$ is $\mathfrak q$?
>
> **Question 2** Let $\mathfrak r$ be an ideal in $B$ such that
>
> (a) $\mathfrak r^c=\mathfrak q$,
>
> (b) $\mathfrak r$ is maximal among the ideals satisfying (a).
>
> Is $\mathfrak r$ primary?

It is easy to see that "yes to Question 2" implies "yes to Question 1".

Question 2 can be restated as follows:

> **Question 2'** Let $B$ be a commutative ring and $A$ a subring. Assume that $(0)\subset A$ is primary and that $A\cap\mathfrak b\neq(0)$ for any nonzero ideals $\mathfrak b$ in $B$. Does this imply that $(0)\subset B$ is primary?

**EDIT 1.** I changed the notation following user26857's comments.

**EDIT 2.** The lines below reduce the problem to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2389114/660).

Let $K$ be a field and set $A:=K[\varepsilon]$ with $\varepsilon^2=0$ but $\varepsilon\ne0$. Note that $(0)\subset A$ is primary. We will define a ring $B$ which contains $A$. Then $(0)\subset A$ will be a contracted primary ideal, and we hope that $(0)\subset A$ will *not* be the contraction of a primary ideal of $B$.

We define $B$ by 
$$
B=K[X,Y_1,Y_2,\dots]/\mathfrak b=K[x,y_1,y_2,\dots]
$$ 
(obvious notation) with 
$$
\mathfrak b=(X^2Y_1)+\sum_{i\ge2}(X^nY_n-XY_1),
$$
and we embed $A$ in $B$ by setting $\varepsilon:=xy_1$. We get $\varepsilon x=0$ and $\varepsilon=x^ny_n$ for all $n\ge1$; in particular $\varepsilon\in(x^n)$ for all $n\ge1$.

We claim that our problem has been reduced to the statement $XY_1\notin\mathfrak b$, or, equivalently, to the statement $\varepsilon x\ne0$.

Indeed, assuming the above statement, let $\mathfrak q$ be a primary ideal of $B$. If we had $\varepsilon\notin\mathfrak q$ and $x^n\notin\mathfrak q$ for all $n\ge1$, then $x$ would be a non nilpotent zero divisor in $B/\mathfrak q$, contradicting the assumption that $\mathfrak q$ is primary. Thus we have $x^n\in\mathfrak q$ for some $n\ge1$, or $\varepsilon\in\mathfrak q$. But, since $\varepsilon\in(x^n)$, we get $\varepsilon\in\mathfrak q$ in both cases, and 
$\mathfrak q$ contracts to $(1)$ instead of contracting to $(0)$.

Thus, if we could prove $XY_1\notin\mathfrak b$, our argument would be complete.

Let $\mathfrak b_n$ be the ideal 
$$
(X^2Y_1,X^2Y_2-XY_1,\dots,X^nY_n-XY_1)
$$ 
of $K[X,Y_1,\dots,Y_n]$. It suffices to prove that we have $XY_1\notin\mathfrak b_n$ for all $n\ge2$. One can use Groebner basis to prove this for a given $n$, but I haven't been able to prove it for all $n\ge2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In view of Edit 2, it is clear that [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2389326/660), due to user26857, shows that a contracted primary ideal is not always the contraction of a primary ideal. Thanks a lot again to user26857!