# $xy_1\in\langle x^2y_1,x^2y_2-xy_1,\dots,x^ny_n-xy_1\rangle$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, groebner-basis

Let $k$ be a field; let $n$ be an integer $\ge2$; let $x,y_1,\dots,y_n$ be indeterminates; and let $I$ be the ideal 
$$
\langle x^2y_1,x^2y_2-xy_1,\dots,x^ny_n-xy_1\rangle
$$ 
in $k[x,y_1,\dots,y_n]$.

> Do we have $xy_1\in I$?

Comment: For $n=3$ Macaulay2 says "false".

Comment: Thanks! My hope is that the answer is "false" for any $n\ge2$ (and any field $k$).

Comment: I don't think "any $n\ge 2$" changes something.

Comment: @user26857 - Do you have a precise argument? I explained the motivation in the second edit to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2305463/660.

Comment: I think the following argument for $n=3$ can be generalized: If $xy_1\in I$ then $y_1\in (xy_1,xy_2-y_1,x^{2}y_3-y_1)$. For $y_1=x^{2}y_3$ we get $x^2y_3\in(x^3y_3,xy_2-x^2y_3)$. For $y_2=xy_3$ we get $x^2y_3\in(x^3y_3)$, false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you very much to user26857 who explained in a comment that the answer is negative for the following reason:

Assume by contradiction 
$$
xy_1\in\langle x^2y_1,x^2y_2-xy_1,\dots,x^ny_n-xy_1\rangle.
$$ 
Dividing by $x$ we get 
$$
y_1\in\langle xy_1,xy_2-y_1,x^2y_3-y_1,\dots,x^{n-2}y_{n-1}-y_1,x^{n-1}y_n-y_1\rangle.
$$ 
Setting $y_i:=x^{n-i}y_n$ for $1\le i\le n-1$ we get $x^{n-1}y_n\in\langle x^ny_n\rangle$, which is false.