If $f: A \to B$ is a homomorphism, then a prime $\mathfrak{p} \subseteq A$ is the contraction of a prime in $B$ iff $\mathfrak{p}^{ec} = \mathfrak{p}$
This is proposition 3.16 in Atiyah-Macdonald, and I'm a little confused at the proof. Their notation is $S = f(A \setminus \mathfrak{p})$, and $\mathfrak{p}^{ec}$ means to extend the prime ideal then contract it. In one line of their proof, they make the following claim:
"$\mathfrak{p}^e$ does not meet $S$, therefore by (3.11) its extension in $S^{-1}B$ is a proper ideal..."
However, the relevant part (or what I think they're using) of (3.11) says:
"The prime ideals of $S^{-1}B$ are in bijection with the prime ideals of $B$ which don't meet $S$"
This is fine, but we don't necessarily have that $\mathfrak{p}^e$ is prime, so I don't see how we can use this (or any of the other parts of the proposition). My idea is that we can find a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ that contains $\mathfrak{p}^e$ that doesn't intersect $S$, then use the proposition and use containment, but I'm not actually sure how to prove we can find such an ideal. Maybe I'm just not seeing something simple though! Thanks for any help!

Also, I'll just link this other question in the comments here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1927909/prime-ideal-is-a-contraction-of-some-prime-ideal-iff-pec-p
This tackles the same question, but has a different problem and I don't think it answers mine. Either way is probably useful to leave.

Assume that $\mathfrak{p}^{ec} = \mathfrak{p}$. We need to show that there is a prime that contracts to $\mathfrak{p}$.
As the OP pointed out, $\mathfrak{p}^e$ may not be prime in $B$. We will find a prime containing $\mathfrak{p}^e$ that contracts to $\mathfrak{p}$.  Let $S$ be the image of $A - \mathfrak{p}$ in $B$. It is easy to check that $S$ is a multiplicatively closed set in $B$.
Now, $\mathfrak{p}^e$ is an ideal in $B$ and we can extend it to $S^{-1}B$.
The second part of proposition $3.11$ of the book tells us that,

If $\mathfrak{a}$ is an ideal in $A$, then $\mathfrak{a}^{ec} = \cup_{s\in S} (\mathfrak{a}:s).$ Hence $\mathfrak{a}^e = (1)$ if and only if $\mathfrak{a}$ meets $S$.

$\mathfrak{p}^e$ is an ideal in $B$ which does not meet $S$ by the way we have chosen $S$. Hence the $(\mathfrak{p}^e)^e$ is a proper ideal in $S^{-1}B$, thus contained in a maximal ideal of $S^{-1}B$. Call this maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$. The contraction of $\mathfrak{m}$ in $B$ is the prime ideal we are looking for.

Thanks! That's super helpful
